# How to get value manual ORDER BY from Query?

Tags: sql-order-by, odoo, psql, odoo-10

I applied query in code for getting values and I received values, but these values came randomly not 'ORDER BY'. So, How to get these values as i defined?

**Below is my query and it's o/p:**

```
"""select distinct src, field_description, value from ir_translation, ir_model_fields where module='P2N_Sales' and ir_translation.src = ir_model_fields.field_description and model='sale.mail.wizard' and ir_model_fields.name in ('status','order','customer','pet_name','services', 'amount','msg');"""
```

[image]

Comment: Just add Order By statement? Why you dont use odoo orm?

Comment: So, what i use in query?

Comment: i already said the same use:
eg: select * from table order by field name asc/desc

Comment: I want record according to i assign in query ('status','order','customer','pet_name','services', 'amount','msg')

Comment: Maybe you should learn how to write queries. You've already written that you have a query without ORDER BY but want it with an ORDER BY. So the anwser is: use ORDER BY... Or you have to change your question, so that the SO community can understand your requirement.

Comment: Ok, My objective is only to get values according to i set in query by any way (Order By also). My question based on this phenomenon.

Comment: I think what Pawan wants is the records sorted so that the field_description column is sorted in the following order  ('status','order','customer','pet_name','services', 'amount','msg') - NOT in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

The order you put the allows values in the "WHERE ir_model_fields.name in()" clause has no effect at all on the final result. You need to add an order by clause if you want the query results in a specific order.

Because the order you want is not a standard alphabetical one, you need to create your own reordering.

If you have a table somewhere with those values in it, you could add a custom sort order column to that table, join to that table and sort on the sort order column.

If there is not a suitable table, you need to create your own sortable value in the ORDER BY clause, some thing like this. The else column put any other values at the bottom.

```
<rest of query here>
ORDER BY
case when ir_model_fields.name = 'status' then 1
     when ir_model_fields.name = 'order' then 2
     when ir_model_fields.name = 'customer' then 3
     when ir_model_fields.name = 'pet_name' then 4
     when ir_model_fields.name = 'services' then 5
     when ir_model_fields.name = 'amount' then 6
     when ir_model_fields.name = 'msg' then 7
     else 8 
     end
```